# Symbolicating iOS crash reports on Windows

Tags: ios, windows, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash, crash-log

I have to use Windows for my work so there it's a big deal to symbolicate iOS crash reports there. Are there any tools or tips how to make it more convenient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this application may help you : https://sourceforge.net/projects/ioscrashlogstool/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to symbolicate on Windows. While Apple uses a perl script for parsing the crash report, it relies on `otool` and `atos` to get the actual symbols from the dSYMs for a given address and architecture.

Edit: Only `otool` is available as open source, thanks to Emmanuel in the comments for the hint.

These are your options (to my best knowledge):

1. Ask a friend/colleage with a Mac and provide them the dSYMs and crash reports
2. Get a Mac to do that work.
3. Rent a Mac Mini on a hosted environment (Macminicolo, MacStadium, etc.)
4. Use a third party crash reporting service, which provides symbolication features and is also able to symbolicate apple formatted crash reports (HockeyApp.net supports that)
5. Use a third party crash reporting service, which collects your crashes and symbolicates them right away. There are multiple services on the market for this.

(Disclaimer: I am a Co-Founder of HockeyApp)

Comment: otool is open source, it is part of [cctools](https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-845/otool/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still would need `atos`.

Comment: Check out atosl which I believe is an open source version of atos.